# Dictionary "of or" Explanation Meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

When I look at the meaning of a word in a dictionary, sometimes the explanation starts with, *of or...*

For example, the explanation of Sentimental is

> of or prompted by feelings of tenderness, sadness, or nostalgia.

This "of or" always confuses me.
Could you please help me understand it?

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of the terse language used by dictionaries to save space. You are meant to read it as:

*of feelings of tenderness etc* **or** *prompted by feelings of tenderness etc.*

It's making a distinction between describing something as sentimental or doing it for sentimental reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It's a "parenthetical".  "of, or prompted by, feelings ..." -- easier to understand if the commas aren't omitted.